# How to create soft tires like in `Spintires`?

Tags: physics, bullet-physics

Here is an screenshot of a deformed tire in the game Spintires.

[image: spintires]

I would like to achieve a similar effect in my game

I'm using Bullet as the physics library, if that matters.

Comment: Absent one of these developers telling us, there's no way we can know how it was done.

Comment: I'd be inclined to apply this deformation in the vertex shader. Sample a heightmap or proxy geometry for the terrain under the vertex being transformed, and apply a deformation proportional to the proximity of the vertex to the terrain.